# Given a timestamp, get total N. of seconds in the hour

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, timestamp

Given a Pandas timestamp:

```
> pd.Timestamp.now()
  Timestamp('2015-09-02 19:33:55.714410')
```

how can I get the **total** number of minutes (or seconds, or microseconds) in the hour? (as a decimal fraction of the total). Note that I am not asking for how many **full** minutes (or seconds or microseconds) have elapsed.

Comment: if its not the trivial soln, then pls show what you are looking for..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
t = pd.Timestamp.now()
(t - t.normalize()).total_seconds()
```

**EDIT**

To get the total number of seconds in the hour:

```
t = pd.Timestamp.now()
(t - t.to_period("H").start_time).total_seconds()
```

Comment: Thanks @HYRY. That's close, but `t.normalize()` gives me the timestamp at midnight of the same day.

Comment: I guess I can then add the hours until `now()` .

Comment: This may do it: `(now - now.normalize() - pd.Timedelta(hours=now.hour)).total_seconds()`

Comment: @AmelioVazquez-Reina: to get number of minutes: `(t - t.to_period('H').start_time) / timedelta(minutes=1)`

Answer (score 1):

```
In [2]: t = Timestamp('2015-09-02 19:33:55.714410')

In [3]: t
Out[3]: Timestamp('2015-09-02 19:33:55.714410')

In [4]: t.hour
Out[4]: 19

In [6]: t.second 
Out[6]: 55

In [7]: t.microsecond
Out[7]: 714410

In [8]: t.
t.asm8              t.dayofweek         t.freqstr           t.is_quarter_end    t.isoweekday        t.nanosecond        t.resolution        t.timetz            t.today             t.tzname            t.week
t.astimezone        t.dayofyear         t.fromordinal       t.is_quarter_start  t.max               t.normalize         t.second            t.to_datetime       t.toordinal         t.utcfromtimestamp  t.weekday
t.combine           t.days_in_month     t.fromtimestamp     t.is_year_end       t.microsecond       t.now               t.strftime          t.to_datetime64     t.tz                t.utcnow            t.weekofyear
t.ctime             t.daysinmonth       t.hour              t.is_year_start     t.min               t.offset            t.strptime          t.to_julian_date    t.tz_convert        t.utcoffset         t.year
t.date              t.dst               t.is_month_end      t.isocalendar       t.minute            t.quarter           t.time              t.to_period         t.tz_localize       t.utctimetuple      
t.day               t.freq              t.is_month_start    t.isoformat         t.month             t.replace           t.timetuple         t.to_pydatetime     t.tzinfo            t.value
```

Comment: Thanks @Jeff. Sorry I knew that. I should have clarified the post. I meant to get the _total_ number of seconds (decimal fraction). One option I thought was using a `DateOfffset` to rewind to the beginning of the hour and then using `timedelta` to see total seconds, but I haven't been able to find a `DateOffset` that rewinds my timestamp to the beginning of the hour

Answer (score 0):

```
import datetime as dt   

In [63]:
last_hour = dt.datetime(t.year , t.month , t.day , t.hour , 0 , 0)

In [67]:
(t - last_hour).total_seconds()
Out[67]:
768.129
```